# How to get row value from comma's values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, split

Below is my Table XYZ data

```
Sno  ProgramID    ProgramName
 1      1,2          CCE
 2      3,11         DDU
```

I want output like below passing programID 1

```
Sno  ProgramID    ProgramName

 1      1,2          CCE
```

I am trying query like below

```
select * from XYZ  where ProgramID in('1')
```

No result is coming from above query, my question is single value matching with in query. I dont want like query match with exact value

Comment: Why are you storing multiple *numbers* in a string column?  Something is wrong with your data model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a broken data model.  You can do what you want using `LIKE`:

```
select *
from XYZ 
where ',' + ProgramID + ',' like '%,1,%';
```

That said, you should understand why storing multiple values in a string is *wrong*:

- Numbers should be stored as numbers, not strings.
- Ids should have properly declared foreign key references, which you cannot do with a string.
- SQL has poor string processing capabilities.
- Queries cannot make use of indexes and partitions and probably confuse the optimizer.
- Maintaining the string to avoid duplicates is tricky.
- SQL has a *great* data type for storing lists.  It is called a *table* not a *string*.

Comment: declare @ProgramId varchar(50)
set @ProgramId='1'
select *
from XYZ 
where concat(',', ProgramID, ',') like '%,@ProgramId,%';   i am passing parameter but getting error 'concat' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @mohdmazharkhan . . . Then use `+`.  You originally had SQL Server 2012 and 2014 as tags.  You basically accepted someone's answer who retrofitted the `concat()` after you changed the tags.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
 Select *  from XYZ  WHERE (',' + Rtrim(ProgramID) + ',') LIKE '%,1,%'
```

Use `TRIM` to eliminate any Spaces at the start and end of the string.